# Transformación de button o input de forma dinámica

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, canvas

Estoy realizando un formulario donde pregunto algo.

La idea es que las alternativas tengan apariencia dinámica, pero no logro hacerlo. Averigüé sobre `canvas` y nada. Estaba poniendo una imagen de fondo, pero cuando las alternativas tienen más de dos líneas sale del recuadro.

Resultado a llegar:

[image]

Estaba realizando con CSS mí código:

```css
.alternativa {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  border: 10px solid red;
  position: relative;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.alternativa:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 18px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 13px solid transparent;
  border-right: 26px solid red;
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
}

.mifont {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-8">
    <center>
      <section class="alternativa mifont">
        A. Delaware
      </section>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: Hola @Cesar, ¿puedes explicar qué es exactamente lo quieres hacer?

Comment: Hola @DavidE.LunaM. quiero maquetar lo que esta en la imagen ya sea con button o inputs.

Comment: Ok.  Si tengo tiempo, en cuanto me desocupe te envío una solución del problema con explicación incluida. Va a quedar muy aproximado como se presenta en la imagen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Lea los comentarios que aparecen en código.

### Maquetar botones *quién quiere ser millonario*

Para formar lo que sigue a continuación:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}

:root {
  /* Colores que se utilizarán */
  --color-base: #071f5f;
  --color-secundario: #0e3ebe;
  --color-terciario: #efb40c;
  --color-terciarioB: #be8f0a;

  /* Posición superior de los botones, menos el primero */
  --margin-top: 10px;

  /* Grosor de la línea que pasa a través
     de los botones */
  --grosor: 7px;

  /* Altura de los botones */
  --height: 35px;

  /* Anchura máxima del contenedor principal */
  --width: 800px;

  /* El relleno de los botones en porcentaje
     que será directamente proporcional a la 
     inclinación de sus ángulos en función de la
     posición de sus 4 nodos principales: */
  --relleno: 10%;

  /* Se emulará el padding pero en el color 
     de relleno del botón para dar la sensación
     visual de estar con bordes degradados de 
     3px de grosor: */
  --separacion: 3px;

  /* Formas */
  --formas: polygon(
    0% 50%,
    var(--relleno) 0%,
    calc(100% - var(--relleno)) 0%,
    100% 50%,
    calc(100% - var(--relleno)) 100%,
    var(--relleno) 100%
  );

  /* Imágenes de fondo de los botones */
  --fondoA: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(14, 62, 190, 0.6) 20%, rgba(7, 31, 95, 0.9) 80%);
  --fondoB: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(7, 31, 95, 0.9) 20%, rgba(14, 62, 190, 0.6) 80%);
}

/* Contenedor principal */
.millonario {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: var(--width);
}

/* En este *item* van a estar los botones y las líneas 
   que atraviesan los botones */
.millonario__item {
  position: relative;
  min-height: var(--grosor);
  transition: 300ms ease;
}

/* Margen superior del contenedor
   de los botones, menos el primer contenedor */
.millonario__item:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

/* Línea cilíndrica que atraviesa los botones de opciones de
   «quién quiere ser millonario» */
.millonario__item::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  /* Fondo de las líneas que van entre los botones. Es la
     que le da la apariencia 3D */
  background-color: var(--color-base);
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, var(--color-base), white, var(--color-secundario));

  /* Altura de las líneas que están entre los botones*/
  height: var(--grosor);
}

/* Se mostrarán o no las líneas que atraviesan los botones
   en función del ancho disponible en el dispositivo en el
   se visualicen */
@media screen and (min-width: 450px) {
  .millonario__item::before {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 449px) {
  .millonario__item::before {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* Se comportará como cajas flexibles o no en función 
   del ancho disponible en el dispositivo en el que se
   visualicen */
.opciones {
  display: flex;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 449px) {
  .opciones {
    display: block;
  }
}

.opciones__item {
  --padding: 50px;
  --divisor: 4;

  transition: 300ms ease;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  position: relative;
  min-height: var(--height);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 450px) {
  .opciones__item:first-of-type {
    padding-left: var(--padding);
    padding-right: calc(var(--padding) / var(--divisor));
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 449px) {
  .opciones__item:last-of-type {
    padding-right: var(--padding);
    padding-left: calc(var(--padding) / var(--divisor));
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 449px) {
  .opciones__item:not(:first-of-type) {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}

.opciones__item::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #d0dcfc;
}
.opciones__item:hover .button::before {
  background-color: var(--color-terciarioB);
}

.button {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  
  /* Relleno horizontal + 4px adicionales en función
     de la posición de los nodos principales */
  padding-left: calc(var(--relleno) + 4px);
  padding-right: calc(var(--relleno) + 4px);
  
  /* Relleno vertical en función del borde que emulamos
     que queremos que se visualice, que es la que rodea
     el botón*/
  padding-top: calc(var(--separacion));
  padding-bottom: calc(var(--separacion));
  
  /* Se visualizarán los puntos suspensivos en el texto que
     no quepan en el botón */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  
  min-height: var(--height);
  width: 100%;
  transition: 300ms ease;

  /* La apariencia deseada en los botones */
  clip-path: var(--formas);

  border: 0;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;

  /* Imagen de fondo que utilizaremos para emular el borde 
     degradado que rodea el botón */
  background-image: radial-gradient(white, var(--color-secundario) 30%, white 50%, var(--color-secundario));
  
  background-size: 120% 100%;
  background-position: center center;
}

.button:active {
  transform: scale(0.98);
}

/* Se utiliza un pseudoelemento que tendrá una imagen de fondo. El
   pseudo elemento tapará la imagen de fondo del botón, pero, 
   dejará visualizar 3px en los alrededores. Fundamental para
   emular el fondo degradado */
.button::before {
  transition: 300ms ease;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: calc(var(--separacion) * 2);
  right: calc(var(--separacion) * 2);
  top: var(--separacion);
  bottom: var(--separacion);
  clip-path: var(--formas);
  background-color: var(--color-secundario);
  z-index: -1;
}

/* Con esta regla se construye una imagen de fondo para el 
   pseudoelemento que tapará la imagen de fondo del botón
   hasta cierto punto (3px)*/
.fondoA::before {
  transition: 300ms ease;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 449px) {
  .fondoA::before {
    background-image: var(--fondoB);
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 450px) {
  .fondoA::before {
    background-image: var(--fondoA);
  }
}

.fondoB::before {
  background-image: var(--fondoB);
}

/* Colores */
.amarillo {
  color: var(--color-terciario);
}
```

```html
<div class="millonario">
  
  <!-- Primera fila de botones -->
  <div class="millonario__item">
    <div class="opciones">
      <div class="opciones__item">
        <button id="a" class="button fondoA"><span class="amarillo">A:</span> Delaware</button>
      </div>

      <div class="opciones__item">
        <button id="a" class="button fondoB"><span class="amarillo">B:</span> Connecticut</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Segunda fila de botones -->
  <div class="millonario__item">
    <div class="opciones">
      <div class="opciones__item">
        <button id="a" class="button fondoA"><span class="amarillo">C:</span> Nueva Jersey</button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="opciones__item">
        <button id="a" class="button fondoB"><span class="amarillo">D:</span> Rhode Island</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Debemos seguir el principio que se describe más abajo.

#### Estructura HTML

Para empezar, vamos a entender un poco la estructura **HTML** que debe formarse para lograr el resultado anterior:

```
.millonario

- .millonario__item

|  + .opciones
|    + .opciones__item
|    |  + .button » A: Delaware
|    |
|    + .opcions__item
|       + .button » B: Connecticut
|   

- .millonario__item

|  + .opciones
|    + .opciones__item
|    |  + .button » C: Nueva Hersey
|    |
|    + .opciones__item
|       + .button » D: Rhode Island
```

> **Nota:** es importante tomar en cuenta que existen varias soluciones que permiten lograr el mismo resultado. Por ahora, en esta publicación seguiremos esta solución.

Debemos formar una cuadrícula como la sigue más abajo:

| Celda 1 | Celda 3 |
| --- | --- |
| **Celda 3** | **Celda 4** |

Pero dicha cuadrícula va a estar contenida en una estructura como la que sigue:

```html
<div class="millonario">
    <div class="millonario__item"></div>
    <div class="millonario__item"></div>
</div>
```

Donde cada par de celdas deben estar contenidas en cada *item* ( `.millonario__item` ). El objetivo es formar las líneas degradadas que atraviesan cada par de botones y para formarlas utilizaremos *pseudoelementos* de la que hablaremos más adelante.

Dentro de cada *item* ( `.millonario__item` ) se anidarán `.opciones` que a su vez tendrá dos *items*, siendo que en cada una de ellas se encontrarán un botón de *quien quiere ser millonario*, que son las opciones entre las que el usuario debe elegir.

> Para evitar que esta publicación se haga extremadamente larga tuve que colocar la estructructura **HTML** que se encuentra justo debajo de la solución presentada al principio de ésta. Recomiendo analizarla.

#### Explicación CSS resumida

Se definirán las *variables* o propiedades CSS personalizadas para facilitar el trabajo. En este caso, se explicarán las partes más complejas del trabajo o menos obvias.

---

**Descripción de las propiedades CSS personalizadas**

- `--margin-top: 10px`: margen superior de los botones.
- `--grosor: 7px`: grosor de la línea que atraviesan los botones.
- `--height: 35px`: altura de los botones.
- `--width: 800px`: anchura máxima del contenedor principal (`.millonario`).
- `relleno: 10%`: el relleno horizontal + `4px` adicionales de los botones será directamente proporcional a la inclinación de sus ángulos en función de la posicón de sus pares ordenados establecidos por `--relleno`.
- `--separacion: 3px`: separación del relleno de color del botón. Emulará a la propiedad `padding`, pero con el color de relleno para dar al usuario la sensación visual de tener un borde degradado de `3px` rodeando al botón.
- `--formas`: en ella haremos que el botón tenga la forma deseada a los botones de *quién quiere ser millonario*. Se utilizó la propiedad `clip-path` de CSS para lograr dicho resultado. La explicación de ésta se hará separada del resto más abajo en esta publicación por ser menos obvia.

  Sin embargo, la sintaxis utilizada es:

```css
selector {
    clip-path: var(--formas);
}
```

Donde la propiedad personalizada `--formas` quedará definida así:

```css
:root {
    --formas: polygon(
      x1 y1,
      x2 y2,
      ...
      xn yn
    );
}
```

- `--fondoA` y `--fondoB`: en estas propiedades personalizadas se definirán las imágenes de fondo que se utilizarán en los botones.

**Explicación de `--formas` :**

Imaginemos que estamos trabajando en un programa de diseño gráfico y seleccionamos una forma; pues, se mostrarán sus *nodos* que señalan la ubicación de sus [vértices](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A9rtice_(geometr%C3%ADa)).

Veamos un ejemplo gráfico (los *nodos* están identificados con números):

[image: Ejemplo gráfico de los nodos]

En la imagen anterior se pueden observar que los *nodos*  están señalados e identificados numéricamente. Cada *nodo* es un par ordenado.

Para lograr que un elemento de tipo `button` , `div` , entre otros, adopten una apariencia similar a la imagen anterior debemos utilizar la propiedad `clip-path` con el valor `polygon()` , siendo ésta una función donde se colocarán los **pares ordenados** que son las que definieron la ubicación de los nodos que formaron los vértices de la figura.

**Sintaxis:**

```css
selector {
  clip-path: polygon(
    x1 y1,
    x2 y2,
    ...
    xn yn
  );
}
```

Los valores válidos de los **pares ordenados** se pueden representar en `px` , `%` , `rem` , `em` , entre otros. Para el caso que estamos tratando, utilizamos `%` . Es decir:

```css
:root {
  --formas: polygon(
    0% 50%,
    var(--relleno) 0%,
    calc(100% - var(--relleno)) 0%,
    100% 50%,
    calc(100% - var(--relleno)) 100%,
    var(--relleno) 100%
  );
}
```

> Puede consultar [Uso de propiedades personalizas CSS (variables)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) y [clip-path - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) para comprender mejor lo que se explica en esta publicación.

#### Pseudo-elementos

Como hemos mencionado anteriormente, la emulación de los bordes degradado de los botones se ha logrado mediante la combinación de una imagen de fondo en ellas y su *pseudoelemento*.

Al *pseudoelemento* se le han definido las siguientes reglas:

```css
.button::before {
    ... left: calc(var(--separacion) * 2);
    right: calc(var(--separacion) * 2);
    top: var(--separacion);
    bottom: var(--separacion);

    /* Esta es una de las más importantes 
     para la obtención de la forma de los botones */
    clip-path: var(--formas);

    background-color: var(--color-secundario);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

En las que se pueden observar que también adopta la misma forma que el botón que lo contiene.

> **IMPORTANTE:**
>
> Es posible que esta publicación le falten detalles por documentar, pero en la medida de lo posible iré actualizando su contenido en aras de mejorar la explicación que en ella se presenta.
>
> He intentado explicar, al menos, lo que es menos obvio para ayudar a entender cómo se hizo el trabajo. Sin embargo, en la medida que tenga tiempo la mejoraré.
>
> Puede probar el código también en [Figura ¿Quién quiere ser Millonario? - CodePen](https://codepen.io/dlunamontilla/pen/QWjKxyx).

Comment: Hey David buena respuesta uno siempre aprende de ti

Comment: Gracias @BetaM. Es posible me falten detalles, pero la iré mejorando en la medida que tenga tiempo disponible.